# Python 2.7 replace all instances of NULL / NONE in complex JSON object

Tags: python, json, null, json2html

I have the following code..

```
.... rest api call >> response

rsp = response.json()

print json2html.convert(rsp)
```

which results in the following

> error: Can't convert NULL!

I therefore started looking into schemes to replace all None / Null's in my JSON response, but I'm having an issue since the JSON returned from the api is complex and nested many levels and I don't know where the NULL will actually appear.

From what I can tell I need to iterate over the dictionary objects recursively and check for any values that are NONE and actually rebuild the object with the values replaced, but I don't really know where to start since dictionary objects are immutable..

Comment: Please update the version for better error messages.
AS @Michel suggested, please use `print json2html.convert(json=rsp)`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at json2html's [source](https://github.com/softvar/json2html/blob/master/json2html/jsonconv.py) it seems like you have a different problem - and the error message is not helping.

Try to use it like this:

`print json2html.convert(json=rsp)`

btw. because I've already contributed to that project a bit I've opened up the following PR due to this question: https://github.com/softvar/json2html/pull/20

Comment: this looks useful. Thanks for the patch.